# Faster way to combine date, hour, and interval columns for large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, series

I currently have a dataset of about 1.2 million rows that contains date, hour, and interval (quarter of hour) columns.

```
Delivery Date      Delivery Hour Delivery Interval
1-1-2017           1             1
1-1-2017           1             2
1-1-2017           1             3
1-1-2017           1             4
```

I currently have a for loop that will combine these columns into the one but I am looking for a faster approach as this will take hours to finish running.

```
for i in range(len(df_rt['Delivery Interval'])):

    hour = int(df_rt['Delivery Hour'][i]) - 1
    minute = (int(df_rt['Delivery Interval'][i]) - 1)*15
    df_rt['Time'][i] = str(hour) + ':' + str(minute)

df_rt['DateTime'] = df_rt['Delivery Date'] + " " + df_rt['Time']
df_rt['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_rt['DateTime'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work (method 1):

```
df_rt['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_rt['Delivery Date']) \
                    + pd.to_timedelta(df_rt['Delivery Hour'] - 1, unit='h') \
                    + pd.to_timedelta(15*(df_rt['Delivery Interval'] - 1), unit='m')
```

A faster method (method 2):

```
def format_row(row):
    return f'{row["Delivery Date"]} {row["Delivery Hour"] - 1}:{15*(row["Delivery Interval"] - 1)}'
pd.to_datetime(df_rt.apply(format_row, axis='columns'), format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```

Timings:

**Method 1**

```
2.53 ms ± 86.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Method 2**

```
1.21 ms ± 67.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution, but it avoids explicit looping through your dataframe:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Delivery Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + 
    (df['Delivery Hour'].astype(int)-1).astype(str) + ':' + 
    ((df['Delivery Interval'].astype(int)-1)*15).astype(str))
```

Given your sample dataframe, this yields:

```
  Delivery Date  Delivery Hour  Delivery Interval            DateTime
0      1-1-2017              1                  1 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1      1-1-2017              1                  2 2017-01-01 00:15:00
2      1-1-2017              1                  3 2017-01-01 00:30:00
3      1-1-2017              1                  4 2017-01-01 00:45:00
```

Comment: This returns a "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'" error

Comment: I wasn't sure if your original `Delivery Date` column was of type `str` or `datetime`. Edited my answer, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

A fun approach is to transform series to give the components of a `datetime` object, then pass a dataframe of those components to [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df[['month', 'day', 'year']] = df['DeliveryDate'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df['DeliveryHour'] -= 1
df['DeliveryInterval'] = (df['DeliveryInterval'] - 1) * 15
df = df.rename(columns={'DeliveryHour': 'hour', 'DeliveryInterval': 'minute'})

print(pd.to_datetime(df[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute']]))

0   2017-01-01 00:00:00
1   2017-01-01 00:15:00
2   2017-01-01 00:30:00
3   2017-01-01 00:45:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```